# Program giving correct output, but displaying Runtime error on Hackerrank

Tags: c, stack, runtime-error

I am asked to evaluate the result of a given operation.
for example if i am given a string `((6-(2+3))*(3+8/2))^2+3` result should be `52.0000`.
only numbers with one digits are given (0 -> 9).
Its a custom problem my professor posted on HackerRank.
I am using CodeBlocks and everything is working smoothly, but when I test the code on HackerRank 
Its giving me a Runtime error, and yet displaying the correct output on all test cases, so obviously it was rejected.

I rewrote the code 2 times and still same result.
I am using C language and Stacks (it's a must).
Please can anyone tell me why I am getting a Runtime error!?
I am still a noob :p, so sorry in advance for any obvious mistakes.

Here is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define SIZE 1000

typedef char element;
typedef struct stack{

    element e[SIZE];
    int top;
}stack;

typedef struct stackFloat{

    float e[SIZE];
    int top;
}stackFloat;

stack createStack(){

    stack newStack;
    newStack.top = -1;
    return newStack;
}

stackFloat createStackFloat(){

    stackFloat newStack;
    newStack.top = -1;
    return newStack;
}

int isFullStack(stack p){

    if(p.top == SIZE - 1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int isEmptyStack(stack p){

    if(p.top == -1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int isEmptyStackFloat(stackFloat p){

    if(p.top == -1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int pushFloat(stackFloat *p, float data){

    p->e[++p->top] = data;
    return 1;
}

int topFloat(stackFloat p, float *Top){

    if(isEmptyStackFloat(p))
        return 0;
    *Top = p.e[p.top];
    return 1;
}

int popFloat(stackFloat *p){

    if(isEmptyStackFloat(*p))
        return 0;
    p->top--;
    return 1;
}

int push(stack *p, element data){

    if(isFullStack(*p))
        return 0;
    p->e[++p->top] = data;
    return 1;
}

int top(stack p, element *Top){

    if(isEmptyStack(p))
        return 0;
    *Top = p.e[p.top];
    return 1;
}

int pop(stack *p){

    if(isEmptyStack(*p))
        return 0;
    p->top--;
    return 1;
}

int stackable(char o1, char o2){
    switch (o1) {
        case '(': return 1;
        case '+': case '-': return (o2 == '(');
        case '#': return (o2 != '#');
        case ')': return (o2 == '(');
        case '*':case '/': return (o2 == '(' || o2 == '+' || o2 == '-');
        case '^': return (o2 != '#' && o2 != '^');
    }
    return 0;
}

char *Infix(char A[]){

    char result[SIZE], e;
    int counter = 0, i = 0;
    stack p = createStack();

    for(i=0; A[i]; i++){

        if(A[i] >= '0' && A[i] <= '9'){
            result[counter++] = A[i];
            continue;
        }
        else
            if(isEmptyStack(p)){
                push(&p, A[i]);
                top(p, &e);
        }
        else{
            top(p, &e);
            if(!stackable(A[i], e)){
                while(!stackable(A[i], e)){

                    result[counter++] = e;
                    pop(&p);
                    if(isEmptyStack(p))
                        break;
                    top(p, &e);
                }
            }

            if(A[i] != ')'){
                push(&p, A[i]);
                top(p, &e);

            }else{
                pop(&p);
                top(p, &e);
            }
        }
    }

    while(!isEmptyStack(p)){
        top(p, &e);
        result[counter++] = e;
        pop(&p);
    }

    result[counter] = '\0';
    for(int i=0; i<=counter; i++){
        A[i] = result[i];
    }

    return A;
}

int isOperator(char op){
    if(op == '+' || op == '-' || op == '*' || op == '/' || op == '#' || op == '^')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

stackFloat Postfix(char str[]){

    stackFloat p = createStackFloat();
    int i = 0, empty = 0;
    float result = 0, conv = 0, e = 0;
    float num1 = 0, num2 = 0;

    for(i=0; str[i]; i++){
        if(!isOperator(str[i])){
            conv = str[i] - '0';
            pushFloat(&p, conv);
        }
        else{
            topFloat(p, &e);
            popFloat(&p);
            num1 = e;
            if(isEmptyStackFloat(p)){
                empty = 1;
            }

            if(str[i] == '#'){
                result = num1 * (-1);

            }else{
                topFloat(p, &e);
                popFloat(&p);
                num2 = e;
            }

            switch(str[i]){

                case '+': result = num2 + num1;
                        break;
                case '-': result = num2 - num1;
                        if(empty && num2 == 0)
                            result = num1*(-1);
                        break;
                case '*': result = num2 * num1;
                        break;
                case '/': result = num2 / num1;
                        break;
                case '^': result = (float)pow(num2, num1);
                        break;
                default:
                        break;
            }
            pushFloat(&p, result);
            num1 = 0; num2 = 0;
        }
    }
    return p;
}

int main() {

    int test=0, i=0;
    stackFloat result = createStackFloat();
    char str1[SIZE];
    char *str2;
    scanf("%d ", &test);

    for(i=0; i<test; i++){
        scanf("%s", str1);
        str2 = Infix(str1);
        result = Postfix(str2);
        printf("%.4f\n", result.e[result.top]);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I think that error means your program is too slow. You need to come up with a faster algorithm.

Comment: What is the input it fails on? Have you used a debugger to trace through the code and make sure it is doing what you expect?

Comment: Generally, HackerRank requires you to come up with clever algorithms rather than the most obvious solution. They'll test it with input that causes the naive algorithm to take excessive time.

Comment: Or maybe I'm thinking of leetcode. I can't keep these challenge sites straight.

Comment: what are the criteria for this problem?  are there multiple test cases?  is the first input the number of test cases?  What is the 'output format conversion' specifier to be used?  Is the output to be followed with a newline?  Please specify the details

Comment: You should get the inputs and run it locally and see where it has a problem

Comment: suggest; searching on stackoverflow for questions about converting from polish to reverse polish notation and vice versa.  perhaps using: `stackoverflow:  convert from reverse polish to`

Comment: Why do you think `SIZE` should only be 1000? Have you tried 100000000?

Comment: Can you please add link of your problem here ? Maybe you misunderstand the problem itself or something like that or just be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is reading an infix expression, `1+2`, converting it to postfix `1 2 +`, then scanning and evaluating the postfix string to produce the result: `3`.

If the intention is to compute the result, there's no reason to actually produce the postfix string and then re-scan it. You can go directly from infix to result.

In your `Infix` function, rather than writing operands to the `result` as a string, add them to your `stackfloat` like you do in your `Postfix` function. When you pop an operator from the stack, instead of writing to `result`, you pop operands from `stackfloat`, do the operation, and push the result back onto `stackfloat`. When you're done, there should be but one value left on the `stackfloat`, which is the final result.

It's a simple modification to your `Infix` function, and it saves you having to re-scan the string.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for not replying earlier, but the problem was with return 1 
in the main function :p
as silly as it may seem, when I changed return 1 to return 0 everything worked perfectly 
and the solution was accepted by Hackerrank.

Answer (score 0):

For 'ACM ICPC Team' problem with node solution I was also getting Runtime error when testing on big data. Then I replaced the `Math.max()` with my own max checker and it solved the problem.